# Cornerstone 6.0.0 eslint update

Tags: eslint, bigcommerce, cornerstone

My team is upgrading our cornerstone from 5.7.1 to 6.0.0 and we noticed on Github after creating the pull request that there are a lot of eslint errors being thrown- all related to our stylesheets. We looked at the code changed from the new release and we noticed there is eslint style added, is there a way we can disable/revert that? It is helpful and my team would like to eventually clean up our stylesheets, but we are not looking to undertake that at this moment.
From my understanding the eslint errors aren't going to throw off our sites, but we were curious to  see if there was a way to disable this anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend raising this as an issue on the Cornerstone GitHub Repo, as I do not believe there is a way to revert it. However in case this is effecting others, a github issue would be helpful for our product teams' awareness.

You can create a new issue on the repository here, https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/issues